# Bound on the norm of a standard normal random vector.

Tags: probability

This is a [question](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/teaching/hdp/hw2.pdf) from Vershynin's free high dimensional probability courses.

Specifically, given $X\in\mathbb R^n$ is a random vector where each coordinate is i.i.d. according to a standard normal, we are asked to show that $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt n\le \Vert X\Vert_2 \le 2\sqrt n$ with probability at least $0.99$ (when the dimension $n$ is sufficiently large).

My first approach was to look at the square, i.e. $\frac{1}{4} n\le \Vert X\Vert_2^2 \le 4 n,$ and use concentration inequality (e.g. Chebyshev) to bound the probability. However this does not worked out as $\text{Var} \Vert X\Vert^2 = 2n$ and thus this does not give a tight enough bound.

I am similarly confused as to why one side of the inequality is $\frac{1}{2}$ while the other side is $2$. I am not sure what approach would lead this sort of bound.

Thus any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2864188/14578, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2071175/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4821/2921, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/656762/14578

Comment: For part (b) I'm assuming that you've used Chebyshev's inequality to get $$\mathbb{P}\left( \left| \Vert X \Vert_2^2 - n \right| \leq 10\sqrt{2n} \right) \geq 0.99.$$ I've not done the legwork but can you apply (b)'s solution to solve (c)? The event
$$\left| \Vert X \Vert_2^2 - n \right| \leq 10\sqrt{2n}$$
is the same as
$$n -10\sqrt{2n} \leq \Vert X \Vert_2^2 \leq n + 10\sqrt{2n}.$$ If you work out what value of $C_1$ (the lower bound on $n$) ensures that $$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt{n -10\sqrt{2n}}  \leq \Vert X \Vert_2 \leq \sqrt{n + 10\sqrt{2n}} \leq 4\sqrt{n}$$ that should work.

Comment: I see, using (b) to then derive a value of $C_1$ worked. Thanks!